# How to report Standard Error from log-transformed data?

Tags: standard-error

I wrote the lm model in R and wanted to know the mean and standard error of each treatment across like 20 responses. Some of the responses were log transformed and some were sqrt transformed to assure model residual normality. I wonder how I can report the information based on emmeans result. For mean, I would assume I should take exp(emmean) for log-transformed response and (emmean)^2 for sqrt tranformed response. And then report original mean. But what about SE? I read that I shall not directly back-transform SE but how I am supposed to report it??? I'm not a stats major so reading formula is really driving me nuts... I attached an example below... [image: emmean result]

Comment: If $E(\log(Y)) = \mu$, $E(Y) \neq e^\mu$. Similarly for $\sqrt{\cdot}$, or indeed any other monotonic but nonlinear transformation. Moments don't just 'transform back' like that.

Comment: Yeah I read that I cannot directly transform the se, but then how can I properly report se? Any other ways to do it?

Comment: Although the mean and variance don't transform back, the percentiles do. so you can report exp(lower/upper CL) and the median=exp(emmean)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion: Back transform both 95% confidence limits of the set of logarithms. For controls, the 95% CI of the mean of the logarithms is from 0.304 to 0.373. So the 95% CI in the original units runs from exp(.304) to exp(0.373), which is from 1.355 to 1.452. This interval is not symmetrical around exp(.338)=1.402, and that's ok (the uncertainty is not symmetrical on that scale).

What would it mean if you back-transformed the SE of the mean of the logarithms? For your control group, the SEM of the logarithms is 0.0176, and exp(0.0176)=1.0177. Unlike the SEM, which is a value you add or subtract, this value (1.0177) is one you multiply or divide by. This approach is not commonly used, so I suggest the CI approach.

Comment: The ability to deal with the transformation is built-in to the **emmeans** package. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `type = "response"` to your `emmeans()` call. That will becak transform the estimates and display standard error and confidence limits.

I guess I would try to dissuade you from trying to report standard deviations of the data on the response scale. Your model uses a log response, so those are not the SDs you used in your analysis.